# What does sts stand for in a .vimrc?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I've been searching around, but the term `vimrc sts` has yet to lead me to an actual explanation of the value. Many people talk about using it for tabs/indenting, but what does it stand for? Is it soft tabs?

I don't like blindly placing things in my `.vimrc` file without knowing exactly what they do.

Comment: `:help 'sts'` Try it out. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> (sts) makes spaces feel like tabs (like deleting)

From [apaulodesign](http://www.apaulodesign.com/vimrc.html)

Comment: Perfect. That's an excellently commented config!

Comment: From your link: "softtabstop".

Comment: Link now seems to be broken.